# All photos from iOS to Mac, only selected ones back

Tags: macos, photos, ios

Has anybody know how to accomplish the following with iOS 8/9 and latest Mac OS:

1. All photos that are made on iPhone are *moved*, (not copied), to the Mac
2. Only selected photos are copied back from Mac to iPhone.

The goal is to have ALL photos on Mac and only selected view on iPhone. Is it possible?